# In my ubuntu 22.04 pip install gives me UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 18: invalid start byte

Tags: 22.04, python3, pip

I have tried updating locales to utf-8 everything is fine. This behavior is observed both in the main system and in a virtual environment, but when I use pip with sudo this doesn't happen, and  the package is installed with no errors.

[image: Image of error]

Comment: EDIT: I answered the wrong way by accident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just debugged codec.py in `/usr/lib/python3.9/codecs.py`. It seems to be receiving some invalid data.

[image]

I went ahead and edited codec.py to handle the exception.When invalid data occurs i simply made it empty.

[image]

And eureka,Now pip works fine and installs my required packages.
I recently corrupted and recovered my home directory in Ubuntu. Then updated it to 22.04 .This may have caused invalid data.

Comment: This is great! Maybe you could do a pull request to python codecs.py. With this help I was able to do-release-upgrade successfully to 22.04. For a note, I had also a corrupted filesystem.