# pip3 broken on ubuntu for me

Tags: apt, 20.04, python, pip

i use Ubuntu 20.04 and python3.8.

I decided to try to create a virtual environment through `python 3 -m venv venv`, this happens:

```
python3 -m venv venv
Error: Command '['/root/venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

And when you try to install or remove a package via pip3, you get this error:

```
pip3 install django
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 305, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 74, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 84, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 132, in user_agent
    zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 122, in linux_distribution
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 676, in linux_distribution
    self.name() if full_distribution_name else self.id(),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 714, in name
    name = self.os_release_attr('name') \
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 890, in os_release_attr
    return self._os_release_info.get(attribute, '')
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 552, in __get__
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 929, in _os_release_info
    return self._parse_os_release_content(release_file)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 960, in _parse_os_release_content
    tokens = list(lexer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 300, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 109, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 140, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

pip3 version is

> pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Before that, everything worked, I do not know what happened. Please help!

Comment: `python3 -m venv venv` shouldn't create the output shown by you. By default, venvs are _never_ created under the `\root` but within the home directory of the current user.
Where and how did you run this commend?

Comment: UPD: I solved the problem this way: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433043/in-my-ubuntu-22-04-pip-install-gives-me-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant